# Devexpress Pivot Grid ShowFieldList Command (MVVM)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, devexpress

On my form I have a button which should show the field list of the Devexpress pivot grid. How can I accomplish this with Commands?

I found the following [link](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfPivotGridPivotGridCommandsMembersTopicAll), but no example how to bind the commands in XAML.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
  ...
  xmlns:dxpg="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/pivotgrid">
  <Grid>
     <dxpg:PivotGridControl x:Name="pivotGridControl1"
                 ...
             />
     <Button Content="Show Field List" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                 Command="{x:Static dxpg:PivotGridCommands.ShowFieldList}" 
                 CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=pivotGridControl1}"
             />
  </Grid>
</Window>
```